# Call to a WCF service, internal variables are NULL

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've created a WCF service running on a network. When a client tries to call one of its function (I'm currently debugging and checking step-by-step when the call comes in), all of the variables defined in the WCF service are NULL (e.g the logger class which is defined on service creation is NULL).

I've tried to search for terms like these, but it ends up empty. Does anyone have experience regarding this issue? The WCF service is created on a different thread than the server application.

Edit:

Client code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Ping();
}

public class Interface : IInterface
{
    public string Ping()
    {
        Logger.Debug("Interface Received Ping through WCF"); //Exception, logger is NULL
        return "Pong";
    }

    public void OpenHost()
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.Info("Interface OpenHost - WCF thread is initializing with ID:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());

            string MachineAddress = string.Format("{0}.{1}", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(),System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName);
            baseAddress = new Uri(String.Format("http://{0}:8732/WCF/",MachineAddress) + "Interface_" + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId.ToString() + "_" + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString() + "/");

            Logger.Info("Interface OpenHost - WCF host will be started with baseAddress " + baseAddress.ToString());

            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Interface), baseAddress);
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IInterface), new BasicHttpBinding(), baseAddress);


            serviceHost.Open();
            Logger.Info("Interface OpenHost - WCF host ready and listening for incomming requests");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { HandleException(ex, "OpenHost"); }
    }
```

Client code:

```
                string sWCFUrl = WCFUrl + "?wsdl";
            //Create object of the Binding
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();

            //Create endpointAddress of the Service
            System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(sWCFUrl);
            //Create Client of the Service
            InterfaceService.InterfaceClient cc = new InterfaceService.InterfaceClient(binding, endpointAddress);

            //Call Service method using ServiceClient
            string ss = cc.Ping();
```

Comment: Can you supply some code (e.g. service creation code)

Comment: are you sure the client is calling it correctly. Have you tried making a test client and passing values?

Comment: i think this is more a "program-logic related issue", without the server code this is impossible to solve

Comment: If you developed WCF REST service then call service method through browser and check output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF service should be as stateless as possible. What I mean is if you want to create Logger class, I suggest you create a static variable. Other than that, any variables that you define should be strictly local to the method. Having said that, I could be misinterpreting the problem, a code snippet will help better understand the issue. If you do want to initialize and have members in the class you may want to take a look at this: [Sessions, Instancing and Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Oh, I see. I was hoping to have some value returned to the client when it called the WCF service.

Comment: Is this value calculated in the method? If it isn't and if it is one of the members whose value you return and if you really do want to do that, go through the link above. It may give you some ideas with the pros and cons.

Comment: I used a static event, and hooked on to that in the main thread. It works great. Thanks for your directions.